# Getting a complete string from server, when assigned to variable in JS it is not complete

Tags: javascript, laravel-5

so I sent a response from my backend to my JS. Server responded with

> {id: 347, name: "Dummy One", date: "July 14, 2020", status: "APPROVED"}

When using `val.name` to a table, it displays the complete value but when I assigned it to a variable, I am only getting the `"Dummy"` value.

Here's my JS:

```
btns = "<td><button class='btn' data-name="+val.name+"</button></td>";

$('.btn').click(function(){
     var name = $(this).attr('data-name');
     console.log(name);
});
```

Comment: The HTML is malformed. You need quotes around `data-name` attribute and add a `>` after the attribute. Try with `"<td><button class='btn' data-name='"+val.name+"'>Some button text</button></td>"`

Answer (score 0):

In your button HTML, you are missing `>` after the `data-name` attribute

As @adiga mentioned in his comment try to change the button HTML according to the comment.

After that, you are assigning the `data-name` attribute value to the `name` variable

try to change it with `var name = $(this).data('name');`